# String Payload > 5Mb , Fails to send back response

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, java-17, spring-boot-3

Controller API is receiving a string datatype as @RequestBody which is having size > 5mb.
Even though a simple string having less than 1 kb is sent back as response , at the front end (client) is not able to receive this response.

But if the request body string is having size < 5 mb , any response will be received at front end.

Where might be the actual issue here ?

I tried setting

server.tomcat.max-http-post-size = 10

But no luck

Is it failing at react application or in spring boot application?

Comment: Are you using axios in react?

Comment: yes @AbdulAlimShakir